# How to Series Wire Secondaries of a Multi Winding Transformer?

Tags: ac, transformer, series

If I have a transformer that has 3 low voltage secondary coils (3V, 6V, 12V) and 1 primary coil (120V), how can I wire 2 secondaries in series? Can you show a diagram with a load? Is there such thing as an anti-series wiring despite the fact that there is only one primary coil? Is wiring different voltages of secondaries of the same transformer advisable? I mean, I know that they're not batteries, and as such, aren't subject to the same internal criteria.

Answer (score 2):

If they are genuine independent **windings** then you can connect them in or out of phase in series. If there are **taps** on a single winding (or otherwise connected internally), then connecting them will lead to problems (such as an overheating or burned out transformer). You can easily check this with a multimeter on ohms range, with the transformer disconnected, of course.

Generally, when in series, you should stay within the the current rating of the lowest rated winding. For example, if you have 3V at 500mA, 6V at 250mA and 12V at 1A you could make 9V at 250mA by putting the first two in series, or 9V at 500mA by subtracting 3V from 12V.

If you are not sure about the relative phase of two windings, simply connect them in series and measure the voltage. If it's additive when you wanted subtractive (or vice versa) then swap the wires to **one** secondary.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such thing as an anti-series wiring despite the fact that
>   there is only one primary coil?

Yes there is. For instance if the 3 secondaries are galvanically isolated then you can, if you wanted make a 15V secondary by wiring 6V and 12V additive with the 3V is opposition (negative). However, there wouldn't be much point because 15V can be made from 12V and 3V additive.

> Is wiring different voltages of secondaries of the same transformer
>   advisable?

It's done plenty of times but usually additive. Subtractive is usually avoided because there are more turns to make a smaller voltage and the \$I^2R\$ losses in the secondary are greater.

The same rules apply to secondaries as batteries - series connections are fine but parallel connections need care.